# Symfony 5 doesn't see the APP_ENV variable

Tags: php, symfony, environment-variables

I'm trying to use different environments for my Symfony application and I run into a problem when my Symfony 5 doesn't want to see which environment I'm using. Here's my .env file:

```
APP_ENV=test
APP_SECRET='secret'
DATABASE_URL="mysql://mysql/mysql"
DB_USER=user
DB_PASS=pass
```

But my application continues using 'dev' environment and when I run `php bin/console debug:dotenv` I get this output:

```
 -------------- --------------------- --------------------- 
  Variable       Value                 .env                 
 -------------- --------------------- --------------------- 
  APP_SECRET     secret                secret               
  DATABASE_URL   mysql://mysql/mysql   mysql://mysql/mysql  
  DB_PASS        pass                  pass                 
  DB_USER        user                  user                 
 -------------- --------------------- ---------------------
```

As you can see, there's no APP_ENV variable at all.
Help me please in which direction should I dig?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try `bin/console about`. Do you have a `.env.local` file or `APP_ENV` environment variable? Those take precedence over the "plain" `.env`.

Comment: Indeed! APP_ENV has been set as one of the 'fastcgi_params' in docker config files. Thank you!!!